# Phonegap device ready not firing in Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I am doing my first blackberry application with phonegap but I can not get deviceready to fire I get alert "entered init function" but callback function is not getting called 
I use cordova 2.1.0
and 5.0.0.469 blackberry

here is Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webworks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("Inside Device Ready");
        }

        // register Cordova event listeners when DOM content loaded
        function init() {
            alert("entered init function");
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

please suggest what might be problem
here is plugins.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.
```

-->

```
<plugin
    name="App"
    value="com.phonegap.app.App" />

<plugin
    name="Device"
    value="com.phonegap.device.Device" />

<plugin
    name="Camera"
    value="com.phonegap.camera.Camera" />

<plugin
    name="Network Status"
    value="com.phonegap.network.Network" />

<plugin
    name="Notification"
    value="com.phonegap.notification.Notification" />

<plugin
    name="Accelerometer"
    value="com.phonegap.accelerometer.Accelerometer" />

<plugin
    name="Geolocation"
    value="com.phonegap.geolocation.Geolocation" />

<plugin
    name="File"
    value="com.phonegap.file.FileManager" />

<plugin
    name="FileTransfer"
    value="com.phonegap.http.FileTransfer" />

<plugin
    name="Contact"
    value="com.phonegap.pim.Contact" />

<plugin
    name="MediaCapture"
    value="com.phonegap.media.MediaCapture" />

<plugin
    name="Battery"
    value="com.phonegap.battery.Battery" />
```

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/ppqV_f8QA8A/-91pcvTwpE0J). you could be missing `plugins.xml`.

Comment: its 5.0.0.469 and it listens to windows event

Comment: Have a valid `plugins.xml` file?

Comment: yes, I have tried all that stuff

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. I haven't worked with BB much. Someone else might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've put your cordova.js and can generate your cod file properly.

Take a look at your config.xml and your widget features:

```
  <feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
```

Those will activate your Blackberry event to your Phonegap app.

You may activate all features to see whether such event you wanted is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can check two things.

1.version of cordova mentioned in the javascript file and version which you are having in the www folder are same.

For example if you have included version 2.1.0 in your .js file as..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

You should have same version of cordova in your www folder also.

2.You need to add following line in your config.xml

```
"<feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />"
```